# How can I disable the "No mail" notice on text-based login sessions?

Tags: server, email, 12.04

I have had an Ubuntu Server (12.04.2) running for quite some time. I was playing around with WooCommerce on WordPress the other day, and wanted to figure out how to get the email notifications to work. In my endeavors, I installed (and uninstalled; well, `apt-get purge`'ed) both `sendmail` and `postfix`.

After I was done playing, and uninstalling everything I had installed (since I could not get either to work), I noticed that a prompt telling me that I had mail would pop-up every time I logged onto the system.

[image]

How can I get rid of this Prompt? I went many, many months without it, and I don't need it or the mail that it wants to tell me I have. Even better, can I turn off the local mail system entirely?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Edit the `pam_mail` line in the appropriate PAM configuration file. For local logins, this is `/etc/pam.d/login`. For ssh, it is `/etc/pam.d/sshd`. Note that this affects all users. By default it uses `standard`, which does print a message if you have no mail. You can change it to `quiet` to only print if you do have mail. See the [pam_mail](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/pam_mail.8.html) manpage for full details.

Comment: Unfortunatly, this is not working for me. I used `sudoedit /etc/pam.d/login` and changed '`standard`' to '`quiet`' on the `pam_mail` line, saved and then logged out, no dice. Even tried a reboot, still no dice. Any reason this should be? After reading through the man page for pam_mail, it seems that the option **I** really want is 'nopen', but This does not seem to work either. :0(

Comment: Okay, I figured it out.

`/etc/pam.d/login` is only respected when logging in via `/bin/login`, or in other words when logging in locally.
since my system is headless, and I ssh into it using sshd, I had to edit the same `pam_mail` line only in `/etc/pam.d/sshd`
[This](http://serverfault.com/a/191252) answer on Server Fault pointed me in the right direction. It seems that PAM is very flexible.

Thanks for your help. :0)

Comment: Ah - you didn't say that you were using ssh, so I wrongly assumed you meant a local login. I've edited my answer to include both alternatives.

Comment: Yeah at the time, I didn't think it would have made a difference. :0)

Answer (score 0):

Just another (simpler) option that worked for me: Remove the file corresponding to your user name under `/var/mail/'. If there is one with size 0, it seems to lead to the message.